# complexity package: disable banner

Tags: printing

The `complexity` package uses the `\typeout` command to print a banner when the package is loaded.

What is the correct way to disable the banner (other than editing the source code of the package)?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{complexity}
\begin{document}$\P = \NP$\end{document}
```

Compile with "pdflatex". During the compilation, you will see something like this:

```
  +----------------------------------------------+
    complexity LaTeX package 
    version: 
    author: Chris Bourke (cbourke@cse.unl.edu) 
  +----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no correct way, I'm afraid:

```
%  Changes made (.76 -> .80)
%   -Added a cool message using \typeout!
```

You can suppress the message with the following trick

```
\let\latextypeout\typeout
\def\typeout#1{\let\typeout\latextypeout}
\usepackage{complexity}
```

Since `\typeout` is almost the first instruction in `complexity.sty`, this will disable printing the "cool message" and redefine `\typeout` to the original meaning.

Answer (score 4):

```
\let\savedtypeout\typeout
\def\typeout#1{}
\usepackage{complexity}
\let\typeout\savedtypeout
```

Comment: Is this kind of approach "safe"? Do I lose any warnings and/or errors this way?

Comment: No it only affects `\typeout` that are actually executed during the package load, any `\typeout` that are embedded in commands defined by the package will execute the restored normal definition when they are run. It would be possible for a package to save the definition of `\typeout` active when it was loaded and use that saved definition (rather than `\typeout` itself) in commands, but that is unlikely in general and does not happen in the case of this package (I just looked:-)